# Problema de acceso a propiedad ANGULAR

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente código en Angular, con un array de objetos, trato de recorrerlo con la directiva `ngFor` pero por alguna razón no puedo acceder a las propiedades del objeto, me dice que la propiedad del objeto no existe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, preferimos el código sobre las imágenes.

Comment: En vez de object, ponlo como Any

Comment: @AlfaRojo fue mas practico declararla como Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución rápida es agregar `?`.

```html
    {{entrada?.frase}}
```

La solución optima sería decirle al compilador el tipo de datos que esta recibiendo con una interfaz:

```js
    //Esto lo puedes poner fuera de la clase del componente.
    interface Frase {
      frase:string
    }
```

```
    this.entradas:Frase[] = [{frase: "Tu frase"}]
```

Comment: Por alguna razón la solucion rápida no me funciono

Comment: Que error te dio?